# Java 8 stream keep elements sorted using groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream

I've a list of elements into a list. Those elements are returned ordered into a Object[]. In that array the first element is a `Document`, the second is a `DocumentRow`.
I'm grouping all rows that belong to the same document together using the `groupingBy` function.

```
List<Object[]> rows = documentRowRepository.rowsExportSTS(from, until);

Map<Document, List<DocumentRow>> rowsGroupedByDocument = 
    rows.stream()
        .map(r -> (DocumentRow) r[1])
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getDocument()));
```

I see that resulting Map is not sorted by Document.id. Is there a way to do that without add more operation considering that the original List is already sorted?

Comment: `r -> (DocumentRow) r[1]` is not retrieving the first element. Indexing in Java starts at 0.

Comment: r[1] is the row. In first position there is the Document

Comment: Oh, nevermind. It gets a row, not a Document.

Comment: if you want to maintain insertion order then accumulate the result of the grouping into a `LinkedHashMap`. `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getDocument(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));`. if you want to sort after grouping see the duplicate or many of the duplicates on the site.

Comment: @OusmaneD. unfortunately I'm working with a Object[]. I can't use r.getDocument()

Comment: @OusmaneD. your solution works fine. Do you want provide an answer so I can confirm it? Thanks

Comment: @drenda glad it worked for you. enjoy!. no need for me to post an answer.